# AVI on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, video

I have about 20 GB of video files that I would like to put on my new iPad.

To my utter surprise, there's no de facto solution for

1. playing AVI files on iPad and
2. syncing **any** filetype on Wi-Fi *without* syncing to the cloud (Dropbox only allows 2 GB, and Acrosync doesn't sync AVI files).

Yeah, technically I can convert them to h.264, but that's kind of troublesome. If an app automatically does this for me then I wouldn't mind.

How can I do this? Surely, I can't be the only one who wants to watch their AVI videos on his iPad.

EDIT:

1. Any free solutions?
2. I want sync over wifi. Stream is a nice feature, by syncing over wifi is a must

Comment: Have you tried [CineXPlayer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cinexplayer-best-way-to-enjoy/id384098375?mt=8)? It looks like it's advertised to play AVI files.

Comment: To answer your question: I use AirVideo to stream everything to my iPad, and for the odd times I want to watch and I am not near my server, I just encode those files to MP4. The latter can be done quickly and works for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of apps which let you watch AVI files on your iPad, some better than others. The one I currently use is [AcePlayer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/aceplayer/id463242636?mt=8) (currently $2.99, though the price has dropped to Free a number of times), and it also supports streaming most every video type there is (mkv, divx, flv, etc.).

Other apps with this functionality include [yxplayer2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yxplayer2/id384824992?mt=8) ($4.99), [playable PRO](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/playable-pro-play-almost-anything/id504195824?mt=8) (sale price $2.99, [free version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/playable-play-almost-anything/id502405034?mt=8) available), and [GoodPlayer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodplayer/id416756729?mt=8) ($2.99).

Comment: In response to wi-fi addition of files: AcePlayer supports streaming AVIs, downloading them with a locally hosted web page you display in your computer's browser, downloading them from the internet within the app, as well as opening them in AcePlayer from other apps.

Answer (score 0):

[Playable](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/playable-play-almost-anything/id502405034?mt=8) covers what your looking for:

- it's free (ad supported, you can pay for pro version to remove the ads),
- You can upload videos to your device using your interent browser (no need for itunes)
- it plays AVI files, and FLV, XVID, MP4, MOV and MKV (not HD MKV however)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said it was troublesome, but if you take the time to queue up these videos in Handbrake, with a target of "Universal", you will find it much easier to deal with them from that point onwards on both your Macs and iOS devices. Doing the queuing doesn't take long (find file, specify destination, click "add to queue") and you can just let them compete overnight, then drag and drop into iTunes. From then on it can't get much easier.

I would venture to suggest it's easier to queue these up in Handbrake than to download and begin using some third party app and to maintain separate viewing queues for ever after.